# User authorization Java SE

Tags: java, authorization

I need to create a user authorization with different user's roles (admin and simple user). Admin will have more functional abilities.
So, what classes or engines should I use to implement user authorization to my destkop application?
Should I use classes in `javax.security.auth.login`?

Comment: I am looking for some desktop application which uses JAAS for authentication and authorization. I got many examples online but those are just for understanding. I want some realistic application to test for my research work. The application may be very small. Could you please give me your application which uses JAAS ? That would be your grat help. Thnaks. (my email id: raginippatel@gmail.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two most common ways to implement authorization in a desktop application are:

- Java Authentication and Authorization Service ([JAAS](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/jaasv2/))
- Roll your own, either entirely from scratch or using something like LDAP for storing and checking user credentials.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, check out [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org).  It's MUCH easier to work with than JAAS and will work with any kind of application, whether it's desktop, web based, or mobile.

Answer (score 0):

[Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) have a good password encryption system. You can use a database or an XML file to store the users and roles data. The password must be encrypted. Then work around your JMenuBar and JMenu's to enable/disable or set to visible/not-visible what every role is supposed to see. With this solution you only need the Bouncy-Castle jar.